# Google Colab: use functions .py from GitHub

Tags: github, import, google-colaboratory

I want to use functions defined in a .py file (uploaded to GitHub) in my Colab project.

I have a GitHub repository with a file "function.py" which contains

```
def SomeFunction():
  return 'it works'
```

Inside my Colab I type

```
!git clone url_of_my_repository

%load function.py

SomeFunction()
```

And I get the following error: "name 'SomeFunction' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `os.chdir` into the cloned directory.